# IBM Worklight - Can't access native Android features

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working with Sencha Touch 2.3.1.

My problem is when I try to access any native android feature (via Cordova). I tried to use the InAppbrowser. But it fails. But it works perfectly when i build .apk using some other ways.

This is the solution which works for me :

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

So, i think the problem is when Worklight accessing the cordova plugins. In the IBM Worklight documentation, they explains that Worklight has inbuilt Cordova support. But i don't know how to get those features.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you use Sencha Touch is completely irrelevant.

Because Cordova is bundled within a Worklight application, to use Cordova features all you need to do is to simply use the API provided by Cordova: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/index.html

When using Cordova in Worklight:

- There is no need to check for "deviceReady"
- Typically most setup steps like adding permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` and/or feature nodes in `config.xml` is already done for you so you do not need to do anything, but this is per-Cordova feature and **you will need to verify this**.

For example, if you want to check what is the device model etc, use the [Device API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device).

1. In `common\js\main.js`, in the `wlCommonInit()` function place the following code:

   > ```
   > alert (
   >     'Device Model: ' + device.model + '<br />' +
   >     'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
   >     'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
   >     'Device Version: '  + device.version);
   > ```

   When you launch the app, once loaded it will display an alert dialog with device information: model, platform, OS version as well as the used Cordova version.

Use similar approach for other Cordova features. For example, the [InAppBrowser API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser):

1. In `common\js\main.js`, add a new function:

   > ```
   > function useInAppBrowser() { 
   >     window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
   > }
   > ```
2. In `common\index.html`, add in the `BODY`:

   > ```
   >  <input type="button" value="open in InAppBrowser"
   > onclick="useInAppBrowser();"/>
   > ```

   When you launch the app, once tapping the button an InAppBrowser will come to view and load apache.org.

Read the following training modules:

- [Adding native functionality to hybrid apps with Apache Cordova](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova)

Comment: I already went through the course u specified. But there is no help on how to use that with a Sencha Touch project. Why i am specifying Sencha Touch is, after building a Sencha App., i will get the following files/folders , **app.js,resources** folder,**index.html**. I don't want to use that _main.js_ you specified. If you have any experience with Sencha + Worklight, please help. And please don't give any further IBM links on tutorials, because i already went through all of them. But still i have no idea how to do that. I also checked example they provided. That also makes no sense.

Comment: It DOES NOT MATTER which FRAMEWORK you choose. The USAGE is the SAME because you are building a WORKLIGHT project, not a Sencha project; follow my examples, in your files and it will work.

Comment: First learn and understand how to use Worklight, and then add Sencha Touch. If you go the other way around and then fail to understand Worklight, that's your problem.

Comment: So, Can you please tell how to implement Sencha's MVC structure while creating it as a Worklight project? Or Where do i keep the files in my Sencha project while coming to Worklight environment?